# PHP application database logic flawed

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have a page on my application that is supposed to keep track of students. Once a counselor accepts the student for a in real life session. doing so the students records are then put into a table called support. My issue is that once that happens for any reason if a counselor needs to cut the session in half and place them back to the que if another counselor accepts the session then I have double, triple, quadruple (etc etc) of the same data being written to the table.  Example :

[image: picture]

is there a way that I can have it so if the session already exists in the database table called support then when the counselor hits session start, rather then inserting it updates? So an example would be :

1. Staff member john accepts student bobby
2. Staff member john has a family emergency and needs to end the session putting the student back in the que.
3. staff member Sara sees the student in the que and accepts the student
4. Rather then the session start button inserting the same session id (example 60) in again it will just update what was already done?

What I have in mind is to set up a Finish student button that will just update the support table rather then just rewrite to the table.

Does this solution seem feasible? - if not what can I do? Sorry for the way I asked this question I am trying to be as specific as possible.

EDIT : New pic for further examples :

[image]

Comment: UI looks pretty nice, though breaks/overflows a bit in the end ;)

Comment: oh no that is me hitting the control + button to zoom in. I would never let that overflow, and if I couldn't fix it bye bye

Comment: No worries, I doubt not what youre doing. I dont want derail this, just to point that it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the table to add a new attribute - "Session completed", that is by default 0, 1 if the student is accepted and currently in session, and 2 if it is completed. When a student is accepted, the 0 changes to 1, and if the student is done, councilor clicks OK, and Session Complete can change to 2 (every once in a while all students with 2 will be erased to not overpopulate the table). If an emergency happens, the councilor clicks Cancel and the 1 changes back to 0...

Comment: shoot I didn't mention that, I also have a table called session_status, with numbers 0,1,2,3 0 = wait 1 = being seen 2 = additional_help 3 = finished

Comment: also my table that is shown above is also SELECT from rows that status = 0 and 2